# How can I create a checkbox component based on value of TextField?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox, material-ui, textfield

I have 3 components - 2 textfield and 1 checkbox Material UI component. I want the checkbox checked only if there is value in textfield component? What would be the best way to implement this?

Here is the link to my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-utbtl?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have updated my code but facing blockers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the availability of text content using the **length** property.

```
const isTextFieldsNotEmpty = text1.length > 0 && text2.length > 0;
```

You can check my solution here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2fce5?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Is it possible to further optimize the code? In my UI, there are other sections where I have 3-4 TextField to check for. So by this logic, I would require to create function and state variables for each textfield

Comment: I think this exaple will help you:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-multiple-inputs-with-single-onchange-handler-react
You can store several text inputs in one state property and handle several inputs text content using one onChange callback